# repair to & repair on

Tags: grammar

I am reading "Insider secrets to hydraulic" book and there are two sentences:

1. As with any repair, the economics of proceeding with **a repair on** a cylinder are ultimately depend on the cost and availability of a new one.
2. If you do carry out **repairs to** hydraulic components yourself, always follow the component manufacturer's repair instruction.

In both sentences **"repair"** is used.
Can you explain to me why in sentence 1) there is construction with "repair on" and in 2) there is "repair to"?

Comment: Because authors come in all skill levels.  If these have been accurately transcribed then this book should be approached by only thinking about what was meant and not how it was written.

Comment: I prefer option 1.

Comment: The devastating part is finding out the manufacture's repair instruction was translate by same peoples.

Answer (score 1):

A repair *on* a cylinder is a repair *to* something *on* that cylinder.

Example:

The repairs on my car included a repair to its radiator (the radiator on my car) and a repair to its starter (the starter on my car).

That doesn't mean I can't say "repair to" for my car, but if I want to be more general or if what I'm fixing has lots of parts or components on it, then I'm more apt to use "on" to say it than "to" to say it.

A third possibility is "repair of."